# Como traduzir cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3

Gerei os **default.pot** , criei a pasta **pt_BR** em:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/i18n-shell.html

```
/src/Locale/pt_BR/default.po
```

e coloquei em **config/app.php**

```
'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'pt_BR'),
```

tradução feita com o **poEdit**, porém não traduz as **actions**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assim a tradução se dá em alguns passos e não é automática precisa da sua intervenção, vou tentar dar um passo-a-passo:

01 - na raiz da sua aplicação rode o comando abaixo para extrair um arquivo com todos os textos que poderão ser traduzidos na aplicação:

bin/cake i18n

02 - Se você executou tudo certinho dando enter a cada passo, o comando vai gerar os arquivos de catálogo (.POT) na pasta src/Locale , abra esses arquivos com o programa POEDIT e traduza linha por linha.

03 - Quando terminar de traduzir todas as linhas salve o arquivo com o nome src/Locale/pt_BR/default.po

Observações:

Se no processo você escolher não mesclar todos os domínios o comando de extração criará dois catálogos o cake.pot (mensagens do sistema) e o default.pot (mensagens dos seus MVCs) traduza os dois. Para concluir não esqueça de setar o Locale pt_BR em config/app.php , aproveite e troque também o fuso horário de "UTC" para "America/Sao_Paulo" no config/bootstrap.php e é isso, aplicação traduzida.